# Can react-native init a project without an Internet connection, using a cache?

Tags: react-native, npm

Is it possible to `react-native init SomeProject` without an Internet connection?

Apparently `npm` has the `--offline` option, forcing installation from local caches. I'm wondering if `react-native` can do that, too.

Comment: I think if you are using expo then it might be possible. but with 'init' not sure

Comment: can you provide some info / links for doing this with expo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible if the package has previously beein downloaded and cached. Use the following command:

npm --prefer-offline

The prefer-offline part tells npm to ignore minimum cache time and just proceed to use available cached package. Also check https://stackabuse.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-configuring-npm/